# WebView2 and Active Network Requests

Tags: javascript, networking, waterfall

How can we know if there are active network requests for the WebView2 control?

I'm trying to determine when a page has finished receiving data dynamically. (For example, DevTools shows the waterfall under the 'Network' tab.)